# How to pass multiple values in place of single value to a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, execute

I have a stored procedure, and it is executed perfectly, when i am using:

```
exec spSampleAmount 12212,0
```

Now i need to pass like "12212,12213,12214,12215" and these values coming from another query. How to pass this query result to a 2 argument stored proc.

```
exec spSampleAmount param1,param2;
```

param1 have set of values.

Comment: If the stored procedure takes two parameters, you can't pass more (unless there are optional parameters).  Rewrite the stored procedure.

Comment: rewrite spSampleAmount that split "12212,12213,12214,12215" and use it.so you also need stringsplit function that will "12212,12213,12214,12215" and return table.Or don't modify spSampleAmount rather loop in proc where you calling this and split param and pass one by one.Ball is in your court now.

Answer (score 1):

Store the output of first query in parameter. First declare the parameter and then assign the value of first query to that parameter then call `exec` command to execure the stored procedure.

```
DECLARE @V_Param1 VARCHAR(1000);

SELECT @V_Param1 = Rest of query

EXEC spSampleAmount @V_Param1, 0
```

Comment: @shah Thanks for the answer

SELECT ID FROM Header WHERE Date BETWEEN '10-1-2013' AND '11-1-2013'



the above query returned 12 rows, so error is coming like this "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

Comment: @SubbaraoGaddam Please add full code so I can understand and give you the answer

Comment: I need to pass multiple values to a param1.. of a SP at the time of execution

Comment: i don't have access to edit the SP because it is used in some where else also. So i need to do it at execution level only

Answer (score 1):

if it is called by SSRS it's possible, i don't know exactly how it works, but it is.

You have 2 ways to call a stored procedure from ssrs, sql query and write execute. Or select execute stored procedure.

In that way you have the possibility to pass a selection from a multiple item selection combobox to the stored procedure and in your stored procedure do a : where myparam in (@paramreceived).

It should be also possible in .Net.

I tried to do that in tsql and i never succeeded, so i'm interrested too if there is a solution to that problem